# How can I call an NSMutableArray created in another class?

Tags: xml, parsing, class, nsmutablearray, tableview

I have created one class XMLParsing.h/m, which loads a URL, parses an XML into NSStrings and NSNumbers, and then puts the parsed strings into an NSMutableArray called "showArray".

The XML is set up so that each child has an "id", and then other variables. So in the array, we have:

NSNumber: (the id from the XML)
NSString: (title)
NSString: (description)
NSString: (venue)

In another class, ShowDetailViewController.h/m, I want to load that array and it's objects, and, based on the TableView Cell clicked in a previous view, I would like for the items in the nib (labels in this case) to be populated with the "id-specific" data from the XML. So, for instance:

In my TableView, the titles of each show are listed (from the XML). A user clicks on a title, and another view is pushed, which displays that show's title, description, and venue, as loaded from the parsed XML.

All of this parsed data exists in an NSMutableArray, but my problem is, I can't seem to access the objects in another class. The array keeps returning null.

I have tried:

In my ShowDetailViewController.m, I have one method which contains:

```
XMLParsing *xmlClass = [[XMLParsing alloc] init];
NSLog(@"The array contains: %@", xmlClass.showArray);
[xmlClass release];
```

However, the result is always "The array contains: (NULL)"
If I run the same NSLog within the XMLParsing class itself, it will print the entire array. So, I know the data is parsing into strings just fine, and it IS being stored in the array. However, it's not accesible outside of the class in which it is made.

In the XMLParsing Class, I have made the NSMutableArray *showArray, a non-atomic, retained, and synthesized property. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance for all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This in your XMLParsing Class

```
-(NSMutableArray *)parseURL  {


self.showarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSString *getURLString = @"url"

NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:getURLString];

xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];

[xmlParser setDelegate:self];

[xmlParser parse];

return showarray;
```

}

in your showviewcontroller class

```
   XMLParsing *xmlClass = [[XMLParsing alloc] init];

        anyArray = [xmlClass parseURL];
```

Comment: Sorry, I suppose it's my fault I was unclear, I am parsing using a 3rd party API - TBXML (for cocoa touch). My bad on not mentioning this. I will try your suggestion with some modifications and get back to you! Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Thanks, Worked great, just replaced the parsing code with my [self myParseMethod]